# Check for string '(xx%)' at the end of a string

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I check if a string has any value like

```
(xx%)
```

at the end?

I would like to extract that value (remove it from the string and save the value in a variable)

**Example:**

```
Lorem ipsum (34%)
```

should become

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum';
$value = 34;
```

Comment: Only 2 *digits*? What about `Foo(1%)` ?

Comment: Writing code would be a good start...

Comment: `if(strpos($string, '(xx%)') !== false) { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using capturing groups:

```
$original = 'Lorem ipsum (34%)';

if (preg_match('/(.*)\s*\((\d+)%\)$/', $original, $matched)) {
    $string = $matched[1];  // 'Lorem ipsum'
    $value = $matched[2];   // '34'
} else {
    // do something else if it does not match.
}
```

Comment: And if there is no such value -> $string = $original?

Comment: @user3142695, `preg_match` will return 1 if there's match, 0 otherwise. You can use it as a predicate. I updated answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$subject = "Lorem ipsum (34%)";
$pattern = '/^([^\(]*)\(([0-9][0-9]?)%\)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$string = $matches[1][0];
$value = $matches[2][0];
?>
```

I don't have access to a machine with PHP on it at the moemnt, but this should be darn close to y our answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*)\((\d+)%\)$
```

Brief explanation ^
* `^` marks the start of line
* `(.*)` capture the text until a `(`
* `(\d+)%` match at least one number followed by % and capture only the number
* `\)$` match a `)` at the end of line

[Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/fC0pS8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = "Lorem ipsum (34%)";
$pattern = '/\(\d\d%\)$/';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);


if ($matches) { preg_match('/\d\d/', array_pop($matches), $digits); }
if ($digits) { 
    $value = array_pop($digits); 
    $string = substr($subject, 0, -5); }

echo $value;
echo $string;
```